# .hide() divs before js file loads

Tags: jquery, css, hide

I have some `<div>` elements that I hide using

```
$('.secretdivs').hide()
```

Unfortunately, they are visible until my js script loads. This causes the `div`s to flicker when the page loads. How can I have them hidden before the script loads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide the divs via CSS rather than jquery.

```
.secretdivs { display: none;}
```

This is far more efficient than using jquery to hide them.

Answer (score 2):

Add this style to your element:
`style="display:none;"`

That should do it.

Comment: this but put it in the css not inline. so with css, `.secretdivs{display:none;}`

Comment: Yeah, good point. I didn't notice that it was a class :D 'Course, if it weren't a class or ID it'd be better like this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use css class that will be applied to elements yoou want hidden:

```
.secretdivs{
    display:none;
}
```